# Correct the word "urgent" with repeated letters using regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to change "Hitttt Urrggeennnttt Rrare" with "Hitttt Urgent Rrare" using regex, or "Uupppp Uuurrggeent Upp!! Barrkk" with "Uupppp Urgent Upp!! Barrkk". (All words are in camel case.)

I mean I just want to correct the 'urgent's, not the other words.

```
s.replaceAll("([Urgent])\\1+", "$1");
```

does not work. Any idea?

Comment: Just create a regex for "urgent" where each letter can appear one or more times. Isn't that hard. Have you at least tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hitttt Urrggeennnttt rrare";
    s = s.replaceAll("(?i)u+r+g+e+n+t+", "Urgent"); // ?i ==> case insensitive
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

> hitttt Urgent rrare

Comment: Is there a huge difference between use (?i) at the begining or /.../i (qualifier) ? I never saw (?) *Match the remainder of the pattern* used like this but that's interesting.
regex101 count 8 steps for (?i) but only 7 for *i* qualifier.

Comment: @SimonPA - `(?i)` is for java. `//i` isn't :)